# Why does UITableView show the same view for each cell?

Tags: swift

I have been trying to implement a `UISegmentedControl` in the first cell of a `UITableView` and it has worked however it shows for each cell following the first one. How do I fix this

```
import UIKit

class InfoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    convenience init() {

        self.init(style: UITableView.Style.grouped)

    }

    var image: UIImage?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) 

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let genderItems = ["Male", "Female"]
            let genderControl = UISegmentedControl(items: genderItems)
            genderControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(genderChanged), for: .valueChanged)
            cell.contentView.addSubview(genderControl)
            genderControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            genderControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            genderControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        }
        return cell

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == 0{
            return view.frame.height/3
        }
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


        if section == 0 {

            let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = self.image
            return imageView
        }

        return nil

    }

    @objc func genderChanged(){

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #1**

Remove this

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 5
}
```

and return 5 here

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 5
}
```

**Solution #2**

Replace

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
```

to

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
```

in both options you should implement else for that if to return the other needed cell

also move this line to `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```